# (Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module) Not Found.

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to create a SharePoint 2016 AddIn in VisualStudio Professional 2015 with Updates3 but after doing so I'm getting the following Errors:

> File '../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' was not found.SharePointAddIn2   c:\users\bpopnikolov\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SharePointAddIn2\SharePointAddIn2\Pages\Default.aspx
>
> Cannot initialize the following SharePoint project item: 'Scripts'. This item requires a type provider that has the following ID, but this provider could not be found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module'. Reinstall the extension that provides this item type, or remove the item from your project.    Solution 'SharePointAddIn2'
>
> Cannot initialize the following SharePoint project item: 'Content'. This item requires a type provider that has the following ID, but this provider could not be found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module'. Reinstall the extension that provides this item type, or remove the item from your project.    Solution 'SharePointAddIn2' ‎(0 projects)
>
> Cannot initialize the following SharePoint project item: 'Images'. This item requires a type provider that has the following ID, but this provider could not be found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module'. Reinstall the extension that provides this item type, or remove the item from your project. Solution 'SharePointAddIn2' ‎(0 projects)
>
> Cannot initialize the following SharePoint project item: 'Pages'. This item requires a type provider that has the following ID, but this provider could not be found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module'. Reinstall the extension that provides this item type, or remove the item from your project.  Solution 'SharePointAddIn2' ‎(0 projects)

I have installed:

> https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/#downloadvs
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by uninstalling and reinstalling the whole Visual Studio again using the https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller